# Subir imagenes y archivos pdf con php y mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Hola tengo este codigo que he podido armar, solo me suben las imagenes,mas cuando selecciono un archivo pdf, este no se guarda en el la carpeta indicada, podrian indicarme cual seria mi error , esto es lo que tengo

```
function AgregarRecepcionCertificado(){
    $Recepciones= new Recepciones();  
    $tipoArchivo=explode("/",$_FILES["archivo"]["type"]);
    $ubicacion="ARCHIVOS_FOODZ\CERTIFICADO_SENASA";
    $Recepciones->n_item=$_REQUEST["item"]; 
    $Recepciones->NumRecepcion=$_REQUEST["NumRecepcion"];   
    $Recepciones->IdProveedor=$_REQUEST["IdProveedor"];     
    $Recepciones->IdCoordinador=$_REQUEST["IdCoordinador"];     
    $Recepciones->CodProducto=$_REQUEST["CodProducto"];     
    $Recepciones->Chofer=$_REQUEST["Chofer"];       
    $Recepciones->NomImagenR=$ubicacion."/".$_REQUEST["NomImagen"].'.'.$tipoArchivo[1];     
    $Recepciones->NomImagen=$_FILES['archivo']['name'];     


    $nombre_img=$_FILES['archivo']['name'];
    if (($_FILES['archivo']['name'] == !NULL) && ($_FILES['archivo']['size'] <= 500000)) 
    {
        //indicamos los formatos que permitimos subir a nuestro servidor
        if (($_FILES["archivo"]["type"] == "image/gif")
            || ($_FILES["archivo"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
            || ($_FILES["archivo"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
            || ($_FILES["archivo"]["type"] == "image/png")
            || ($_FILES['archivo']['type'] == "application/pdf")
            )
        {
            //$foto=$ubicacion."/".$cant.".jpg";
            $NomImagenR=$ubicacion."/".$_REQUEST["NomImagen"].'.'.$tipoArchivo[1];
            // Muevo la imagen desde el directorio temporal a nuestra ruta indicada anteriormente
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'],$NomImagenR);
        } 
        else 
        {
        //si no cumple con el formato
            echo "No se puede subir una imagen con ese formato ";
        }
    } 
    else 
    {
    //si existe la variable pero se pasa del tamaño permitido
    if($_FILES['archivo']['name'] == !NULL) echo "La imagen es demasiado grande "; 
    }       
    $data=$this->recepciones->RegistrarRecepcionCertificado($Recepciones);
    echo(json_encode($data)); 

}
```

Comment: Sale algo en el log del servidor donde estás probando?

Comment: Gracias por contestar,... despues de tantos intentos, encontre el error aqui ($_FILES['archivo']['size'] <= 500000) (esto lo utilice porque primeramente solo estaba subiendo imagenes) , estaba limitando el tamaño del archivo,y el .pdf que intentaba cargar era de mayor tamaño, y no me estaba arrojando el error del tamaño, hasta q revise en el modo desarrollador del navegador..

Comment: Qué bien. Como buena práctica, es sano que en esos casos que algo no cumple una condición, se registre en el log de alguna forma.

Comment: Lo tendre en cuenta... Muchas Gracias..!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

encontre el error aqui ($_FILES['archivo']['size'] <= 500000) (esto lo utilice porque primeramente solo estaba subiendo imagenes) , estaba limitando el tamaño del archivo,y el .pdf que intentaba cargar era de mayor tamaño, y no me estaba mostrando el error del tamaño, hasta q revise en el modo desarrollador del navegador..